# OdbcConnection only works if connection string is entered directly

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#, so apologies if this is a stupid question. I want to connect to an ODBC Data source. Therefore I created a data source with the ODBC wizard. Now I want to use it within my c# app.

But here I encountered some strange behavior. The connection works perfectly if I create the connection object with the connection string as the input parameter like this:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=test; UID=testuser; PWD=testpass");
```

But if I first build the connection string from a textbox and a passwordbox and use this string as the input parameter:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
```

I get the error message:

```
Error: (IM002) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.
```

The previously built connection string seems to be exactly as the directly inserted one! I checked it via Debug...

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here are my controls to create the string:

```
string uid = "";
private void uid_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        uid = uid_box.Text;
    }

private void queryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
String pass = pass_box.Password;
String dsn = "test";
String ConnectionString =
            "DSN = " + dsn + "; " +
            "UID=" + uid + "; " +
            "PWD=" + pass;
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(@ConnectionString); //doesn't work
OdbcConnection conn1 = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString); //doesn't work
```

Comment: If the string actually would be exactly the same, it would actually work. Double-check, don't stop at _"seems to be the same"_. Stop at _"is absolutely and exactly the same"_. So either the variable `ConnectionString` is something else, or you're not properly assigning the input to it. Show how you do the latter, and show what you enter.

Comment: can you please share the code where you are reading the values from the controls and passing it to odbcConnection?

Comment: Are you going to debug your code, or do you want us to debug your code without seeing it?

Comment: Have you defined DSN "test" in control panel?

Comment: As mentioned above, clearly something isn't the same. You say that it is when you debug, so could you show a screenshot with the value of 'ConnectionString' when you are in debug mode?

Answer (score 3):

The two strings are not equal. The one you create by concatenating input values has spaces around the equal sign for DSN, ie you create a string "DSN = test; ..." instead of "DSN=test; ...". Remove those spaces.

Comment: Perfect!!! That was it. I would never ever have thought of those spaces.

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer, then :-)

Comment: Oh, and btw use the OdbcConnectionStringBuilder as suggested below. Building a connection string from unchecked user input is prone to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            string test = "abc";
            string testuser = "stu";
            string testpass = @"c:\temp";
            string ConnectionString = string.Format("DSN={0}; UID={1}; PWD={2}", test, testuser, testpass);​
```

Comment: Whoever down graded this answer doesn't understand the problem.  Please upgrade.

Comment: I did not personally downgrade you answer, but, frankly, just throwing some code without any explanation... How would you expect people to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  var str = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
  str.Add("Uid", "testuser");
  str.Add("Pwd", "testpass");
  str.DSN = "test";
  var con = new OdbcConnection(str.ConnectionString);
```

Advantage of `OdbcConnectionStringBuilder` is that it handles values properly even if the values (e.g. the password) contain characters like `=` which would break the manual composition.